# Android - Open Facebook app from link in email

Tags: android

I want to send a link in an email to someone so that when they open it in their Android device, it will open the Facebook app that is installed. Is this possible?

I tried entering `fb://` in the Chrome browser but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why the close vote? Is my question inappropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at deep linking in Android ?

Follow this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android)

It explains some concepts of deep linking your app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put.

You can not force that type of behavior in Android.  the Facebook app supports fb:// and I now believe supports http:// and https://.  The behavior of what happens when someone clicks on a link is based on what apps are installed and how they have opted to open those links and if they have selected a specific app to open those links (once or always)

The Type of behavior you have suggested is frowned upon.  <-- :(

Comment: I have the Facebook app installed on my Android device. But it never asks me if I want to open it when I go to www.facebook.com in the browser...is there a setting I can reset so it would prompt to ask the "once or always" question?